# How to pass data between queries in angular resource?

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

Here is my example this is working fine:

```
var first  = $http.get("/app/data/first.json"),
    second = $http.get("/app/data/second.json"),
    third  = $http.get("/app/data/third.json");

$q.all([first, second, third]).then(function(result) {
  var tmp = [];
  angular.forEach(result, function(response) {
    tmp.push(response.data);
  });
  return tmp;
}).then(function(tmpResult) {
  $scope.combinedResult = tmpResult.join(", ");
});
```

Here the `first, second and third` all work alone without depended. In case for example, 'second`requires some`id`from`first`and`third`requires some`data`from`second`... then how to initiate the`request` with depend on other?

```
var first  = $http.get("/app/data/first.json"), //fetching id
    second = $http.get("/app/data/second.json"), //needs some id from first
    third  = $http.get("/app/data/third.json"); //needs some data from second
```

How that should be handled. also, the query will from by series of adding the request or by series of adding in `$q.all`.

any one explain me with updating my code please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
first.then(function(data1){
  second.then(data2){
    third.then(data3){

    });
  });
});
```

first,second and third are your promises.
Error can be received in second callback function like so.

```
promise.then(function(successData){
  // success here
}, function(errorData){
  // error here.
});
```

Comment: How to get the error message here? `q.all` not required here

Comment: since your one request is dependent on the other, you can't use `q.all`. you can use `q.all` only if any request doesn't depend on the output from other requests.